# Css @font-face не работает

Tags: css, node.js, шрифты, express

Пишу веб-приложение на nodejs, использую express
Шрифты хранятся в /app/view/fonts
Доступ к статике дал:

```
app.use('/fonts', express.static(cfg.fonts));
```

cfg.fonts = require('path').resolve()+'/app/view/fonts'
В css подключаю шрифт так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: local('Roboto'), url('/fonts/Roboto/RobotoRegular.ttf') format('ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #342E37;
    color: #FAFFFD;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}
```

Спасибо

Comment: Сервер отдаёт файл. Если напрямую вбить localhost/fonts/Roboto/RobotoRegular.ttf в браузере

Comment: Попробуй так `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '***путь к файлу***')));`

Comment: Если напрямую отдает, то проблема не в сервере. Подозреваю, что ttf в хроме не хочет работать, лучше поставить заглушки woff/woff2

Comment: Пробовал, не работает(

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл проблему)
Оказывается нужно указывать `format('truetype')` вместо  `format('ttf')`

Comment: ну вы все равно woff добавьте, он рендерится лучше, весит меньше в разы